# integer divides a number, significance

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I get a factor of $5551$, this is the number I want to investigate. Wolfrom alpha, online mathematics page, shows that this number also divdes $74^3-1$. See, bottom of the page: 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5551

This makes no sense, what is the significace behind this. Clearly $74^3-1$ is not the only number $5551$ can divide, since I can multiply any factor to it $x\cdot 5551 = Y$, then $Y/5551$ would divide it.

But what is the significance putting $74^3-1$ , $-1$, in it, why is it there, this might have a deeper explanation.

Comment: maybe it is because, (37x37x37x2^3 -1) are all prime factors = 74^3 -1, and the only one that 5551 divides? is this correct?

Comment: What WA says is that $\,5551 \mid 74^3-1\,$, *not* $\,(74-1)^3\,$. Not sure how or why WA decided that this is an "interesting" enough property to list, but it can be also written as:

$$5551 \cdot 73 = (74 - 1)(74^2+74+1) \;\;\iff\;\; 5551 = 1 + 74 + 74^2$$

In other words, $\,5551 = 111_{74}\,$.

Comment: Why is 5551 in base 74 111?,

Comment: @divx Nevemind I see it now, this is obvious.

Comment: I also see it give in base 12, 3267, which oddly have a prime factor, of 3x3x3x11x11

Comment: I rolled back my edit, because if the the accepted answer makes sense to you then my edit can't make sense to you.

Comment: @dxiv I still have one question. Is this always a property, that the sum, $Y  (a-1)=\left(a-b \right)\left(a^{2}+a \cdot b +1 \right)$ inside, the quadrature term, gives Y? Why is it, then that wolfram shows $2294$  divides $\left(63^{3}-1\right)$ according to the same logic using the quadrature term above should give the 2294 number, but it does not. 

$\left(63-1\right)\left(63^{2}+63+1\right)$

showing that $63^{2}+63+1 \neq 2294$

Comment: where that,  b =1

Comment: @Asael `according to the same logic` The difference here is that $\,\frac{63^3-1}{63-1} \ne 2294\,$.

Comment: @dxiv so that property was exclusive for 5551.

Comment: @Asael Quite obviously, $111_{74}$ defines a unique number. Written in decimal, that's $5551$.

Comment: @dxiv maybe that is why wolfram went all in about this number.

Comment: @dvix i have had this problem in, in "probability of prime factor" would you like to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that  $$ a^3 -b^3 = (a-b)(a^2 + ab +b^2)$$

With $a =74$ and $b=1$ we get $$ 74^3-1 = (73)(74^2+74+1) = (73)(5551)$$

Wolfram Alpha tries to give you as much information as it can, and you pick what you need form it.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense.

Comment: Would you care to answer my other question on "probability of factor", in my profile, see  it.